# how to avoid the figure block the text?

Tags: beamer, floats

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{  \usetheme{Darmstadt}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{%

\makebox[\paperwidth]{%
    \hspace{0.04\textwidth}\raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{./figures/1.JPG}}%
    \hfill{}%
    \raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{./figures/2.JPG}}\hspace{0.04\textwidth}%
}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{ Summary}
\begin{frame}{}
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is my latex file. 
You copy it to a .tex file and run.
my problem is I am adding two figures, i.e., 1.JPG and 2.JPG as two foot figures to the beamer.
But I found the foot figures blocks the text.
[image]
How can I make the txet in front of the foot figures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add this pictures to the background.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{  \usetheme{Darmstadt}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\defbeamertemplate{background canvas}{my background pic}%
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at 
([yshift=2ex,xshift=0.04\textwidth]current page.south west)
{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}};
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south east] at 
([yshift=2ex,xshift=-1ex]current page.south east)
{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}};}}
[action]{}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[my background pic]
\begin{document}
\section{ Summary}
\begin{frame}{}
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
    tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]